# Is it efficient to pass model into a custom dataset to run model inference during training for sampling strategy?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, sampling

I'm trying to design a training flow for sampling samples during training.

My data look like this:

```
defaultdict(list,
        {'C1629836-28004480': [0, 5, 6, 12, 17, 19, 28],
         'C0021846-28004480': [1, 7, 15],
         'C0162832-28004480': [2, 9],
         'C0025929-28004480': [3, 10, 30],
         'C1515655-28004480': [4],
         ...
        }
```

where key is label and value is list of data index

I custom dataset class in which my `__getitem__(self, idx)` function need to calculate distance between an anchor (which is chosen randomly) and other data points. It looks like this:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    item_label = self.labels[idx] # C1629836-28004480
    item_data = self.data[item_label] # [0, 5, 6, 12, 17, 19, 28]

    anchor_index = random.sample(item_data,1)
    mentions_indices = [idx for idx in item_data if idx != anchor_index]
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        self.model.eval()
        anchor_input = ...
        anchor_embedding = self.model.mention_encoder(anchor_input)

        for idx in mention_indices: 
        ...
```

Another way to prevent from passing the model into custom dataset is to  run inference inside the `training_step` function during training.

But I read somewhere that, using dataset and dataloader to prepare data to feed into model might save the training time, as they have parallel mechanism or something like that.

But in fact, I need to compute these kind of distance base on the latest state of weight of my model during training, is this parallel mechanism ensure that? Though in python variable is reference variable instead of value variable.

So which way is more professional and correct?

Edit:

I did both approaches and the second approach much faster than the first approach.

Comment: Can you run your model through all datapoint in dataset initialization and store them. If your ram can't hold all the embeddings, I think it's better to let the model run in training stage as it will take effect of batch computation, which I believe is way more efficient than parallelizing through multiprocessing

Comment: Hi,  as I want the embeddings are computed by the latest weight during training. It means during training my model weight will be updated and the embeddings will be changed. So I can't do it before the training.

Comment: Then putting the embedding model in the training stage is the way to go. Batch computation is always better then multiprocessing imo.

Comment: Hmmm, as I remember, it seem like while waiting for the training stuff, the dataset and dataloader will process for the next batch input. So it's faster than doing a lot of work sequentially.

Comment: Then I think it's best to do some experiment to check if it will create a bottleneck in data loading process. Another thing to add is if you put the model embedding in data loading process, it may create data that come from the old weights? Idk if that would be a problem in your case

Comment: Yup, I'll update when I done those experiments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to have these embeddings computed on the fly during training. The best approach for this would be to move the model computation outside of the `__getitem__` function and into the training loop.

The `__getitem__` method should be used for singular tasks that are disk bound or CPU bound. Computing the embeddings is GPU bound and should be done in batch.

Best practice would be to do something like:

1. use the `__getitem__` method to return the necessary data to compute `anchor_embedding` and other quantities used later on
2. use the `collate_fn` of your `DataLoader` to batch the inputs for computing `anchor_embedding`
3. in your training loop, use `model` to compute `anchor_embedding` and other quantities in batch